# Problem with jQuery Ajax...how do I update two DIVs with ONE ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

```
function ajaxCall(query){
$.ajax({
    method:"get",
    url:"/main/",
    data:"q="+query,
    beforeSend:function() {},
    success:function(html){
        $("#main").html(html);
    }
    });
};
```

This is the entire code that will populate **#main**:

```
<p>{{ num_results }}, you just searched for {{ query }}</p>
```

Suppose I have another div called **$("secondary")** ....how would I populate that with **{{ num_results }}**, which is a part of the code, instead of all of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to return json with the data you need for each area.

```
$.ajax({
    method:"get",
    url:"/main/",
    dataType: "json",
    data:"q="+query,
    beforeSend:function() {},
    success:function(json){
        $("#main").html(json.main);
        $("#secondary").html(json.secondary);
    }
});
```

What you would be returning is:

```
{
    "main": "<p>{{ num_results }}, you just searched for {{ query }}</p>",
    "secondary": "{{ num_results }}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to return a XML or JSON object from the request which will the be used to fill in only the relevant parts. Try something like this:

```
function ajaxCall(query){
$.ajax({
    method:"get",
    url:"/main/",
    data:"q="+query,
    beforeSend:function() {},
    success:function(html){
        $("#main").html(html.main);
        $("#secondary").html(html.secondary);
    }
    });
 };
```

You will also need to update the server-side to return a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression

```
success:function(html){
        $("#main").html(html);
        $("secondary").html( /.*?(?=,)/.exec(html) );
    }
```

Comment: the javascript won't actually see the {{ }} from the django template.

Comment: @Brandon H, ok (i do not use django), updated regexp. it will select anything up to a comma (,)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#secondary').html($('#main p').html().split(',')[0]);
```